# How to get MultipartHttpServletRequest from Servlet30RequestWrapper

Tags: java, http, servlets, spring-boot, netflix-zuul

I'm trying to use Zuul to filter file uploads in order to perform some kind of operations on them but I am unable to cast Servlet30RequestWrapper to MultipartHttpServletRequest without getting a n exception.  I know that the file is in the request because debugging shows it buried in a  [second layer of request,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuDLk.png) but I don't know how to pull this part of the request out into an object.

Also once the request is forwarded on to my application I am able to cast the HttpServletRequest to multipart without any exception.

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: that function isn't available in my "request"  I retreive my request like this: `RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
  HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getRequest();` which is this Servlet30RequestWrapper wrapper class from Zuul

Comment: InputStream inputStream = request.getPart("name") should get you the input  stream.

Comment: Thanks that's what I'm ultimately going to have to do for this filter for now its just annoying because I can't get any attributes for the file like filename.

Answer (score 0):

Read the request from the context

```
//import static com.netflix.zuul.context.RequestContext.getCurrentContext;

RequestContext context = getCurrentContext();
HttpServletRequest request = context.getRequest();
```